# Segfault in compiler when compiling a C code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm looking for a C code which **when compiled** (without running the executable.) gives a segfault. Maybe too many scopes that overflow the symbol table in the implementation, or too many blocks in the C code, that results in an integer overflow in the compiler. I tried some codes from IOCCC, but no luck yet.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which compiler? You can make clang segfault if you create an expression with enough operators (about 15000 seems to do it, but that may depend on your systems stack size).

Comment: Either gcc/clang is fine. Could you point me to some sample code, please? And say my stack size is 8MB.

Comment: Just type in (or rather, generate) any expression with around 15000 operators. Something like `int x=+-+-+-....+-1;` or `int x=1+1+1+...+1` would suffice. And if 15000 isn't enough on your system, just add more.

Comment: Okay to clarify: my answer might not (thanks Johan!) have answered the actual question. Are you after the compiler crashing or the executable? I think I might have misread (very long days unfortunately). There are some entries in the IOCCC that can crash _some_ compilers though nowadays maybe not. But which is it: compiler crashing or the program crashing after compiled and executed ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking for an IOCCC entry that segfaults? Look no further than [2019/endoh](https://www.ioccc.org/2019/endoh/prog.c). It's a rather fun entry. See the [Makefile](https://www.ioccc.org/2019/endoh/Makefile) and [hint file](https://www.ioccc.org/2019/endoh/hint.html) for details. Unfortunately the markup for the html file is terrible (this will be fixed) so you can look at the text version instead [here](https://www.ioccc.org/2019/endoh/hint.text) (though hint files are being renamed in the near future).

Some of the entries from the IOCCC segfault in some systems (see 1984/mullender for example though there's a fix so it works with non VAX/PDP systems). Others without args or wrong types of args. There are many.

One at least is supposed to fail to compile: it's part of a game.

But Yusuke Endoh's 2019 winning entry probably is the best one to answer your question.

## Edit

As Johan noted I probably misread the question. It is possible to make linters crash too with obfuscated code. As far as making compilers crash I know a previous IOCCC entry did in fact crash some compilers but that was a long time ago. That one might be a better match for your question except that it most likely no longer happens.

Comment: I think you misread the question. The question is about finding a program that crashes the compiler not one that crashes when run.

Comment: @Johan You might be right .. it has been pretty long days! But I guess the OP is the one who upvoted it anyway almost immediately after. Not sure. Either way I appreciate the comment. Thank you. .. asked them to clarify in a comment in their question.